# Get values from mulitple checkboxes on different table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have two table rows each containing 3 checkboxes, each within a `<td>`.

I want to display a fourth `<td>` within that row depending on certain rules of which checkbox is checked. Each row is like this:

**HTML**

```
<tr class="tableRow">
    <td>
       <input class="select" class="select" type="checkbox" value="select"/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <input class="voice" class="voice" type="checkbox" value="voice">
    </td>
    <td>
       <input class="mail" class="mail" type="checkbox" value="mail"/>
    </td>

    <!--The <td>'s i want the results of the checkboxes to show -->
    <td class="initial-cost">Initial cost</td> 

    <td class="voicemail-and-initial-cost">VoiceMail and Initial Cost</td>

    <td class="email-and-initial-cost">Email and Initial Cost</td>

    <td class="all-services-cost">All Services Cost</td>  
</tr>
```

And I have this jQuery which kinda works but it shows all the table rows' '...cost' 's rather than for each row individually

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {                 //on page load....
$(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();   //hide all cost elements
$(".email-and-initial-cost").hide();       //hide all cost elements
$(".all-services-cost").hide();                //hide all cost elements


$(".select").change(function(event) {              //when #select is clicked...
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                  //if this checkbox has been checked...
        $(".initial-cost").show();                 //show .initial-cost element
    } else {                                        //otherwise...
        $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();   //hide all cost elements
        $(".email-and-initial-cost").hide();       //hide all cost elements
        $(".all-services-cost").hide();                //hide all cost elements
    }
});

$(".voice").change(function(event) {                   //when #voice is clicked...
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                      //if this checkbox has been checked...
        if ($('.mail').is(":checked")) {               //check to see if #mail is checked too and if it is...
            $(".initial-cost").hide();                 //hide .initial-cost
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();   //hide .voicemail-and-initial-cost
            $(".email-and-initial-cost").hide();
            $(".all-services-cost").show();            //show .all-services-cost
        } else {                                        //but if #mail is not checked....
            $(".initial-cost").hide();                 //hide .initial-cost
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").show();   //show .voicemail-and-initial-cost instead
        }
    } else {                                                                            //otherwise if this checkbox is not checked...
        if(($('.select').is(":checked")) && ($('#mail').is(":checked"))){             //and .select AND .mail is checked however...
            $(".initial-cost").hide();                                                 //hide .initial-cost
            $(".all-services-cost").hide();                                                // hide .all-services-cost
            $(".email-and-initial-cost").show();                                       //show .email-and-initial-cost instead
        } else if (($('.select').is(":checked")) && (!$('.mail').is(":checked"))){        //otherwise if #select is checked AND #mail is NOT checked....
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();
            $(".initial-cost").show(); 
        }
    }
});

$(".mail").change(function(event) {                        //when #mail is clicked...
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {                      //if this checkbox has been checked...
        if ($('.voice').is(":checked")) {              //check to see if #voice is checked too and if it is...
            $(".initial-cost").hide();                 //hide .initial-cost
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();   //hide .voicemail-and-initial-cost
            $(".email-and-initial-cost").hide();       //hide .email-and-initial-cost
            $(".all-services-cost").show();            //show .all-services-cost
        } else {                                        //but if #voice is not checked....
            $(".initial-cost").hide();                 //hide .initial-cost
            $(".email-and-initial-cost").show();       //show .email-and-initial-cost instead
        }
    } else {                                                                            //otherwise if this checkbox is not checked...
        if(($('.select').is(":checked")) && ($('.voice').is(":checked"))){                //and #select and #voice is checked however...
            $(".all-services-cost").hide();                                                // hide .all-services-cost
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").show();                                   //show .voicemail-and-initial-cost
        } else if (($('.select').is(":checked")) && (!$('.voice').is(":checked"))){       //if this checkbox is not checked AND #voice is NOT checked...
            $(".all-services-cost").hide();                                                // hide .all-services-cost
            $(".voicemail-and-initial-cost").hide();
            $(".email-and-initial-cost").hide(); 
            $(".initial-cost").show();                                     //show .initial-cost instead
        }

    }
});
}); //end of ready
```

Now I figured to target just the elements of the row in question, I would have to change the jquery selectors from what is here:

```
 $(".initial-cost").hide();
```

to something like:

```
 $('td').next(':has(.initial-cost):first').hide();
```

But now I get nothing happening at all - not even any error messages in the console.

Please note its not the rules themselves that is the problem, its the fact I want those rules to only apply per table row, not all of them at once. I hope this makes sense and someone out there that point me in the right direction.
here is a JSfiddle of what I have should it help:
https://jsfiddle.net/monkeyroboninja/5n0v0eL5/

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. If that table row is truly repeated, you have invalid HTML and any code running against it will not work. Instead, use classes and event delegation.

Comment: ah you are right about the IDs, now amending....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes lines like this:

```
$(".initial-cost").show();
```

To

```
$(this).parents('.tableRow').find(".initial-cost").show();
```

Which correctly target another element in the same row as the changed checkbox element.

Answer (score 2):

You can drastically simplify your code by encoding the 'rules' of checkbox states. You have 3 check-boxes which gives you 8 (2^3) possibilities. You can capture all these up-front in an object literal and just refer to them in the event handler.

The event handler need only check for a change to state; recompute the state; and check the object to see what to display.

To work on an individual row you just get the closest `<tr>` to the `<input>` that was changed.

So your code can be simplified to this:

```js
var userOptionState = {
  0: 'No cost',
  1: 'Initial cost',
  2: 'Voice cost',
  3: 'Initial and voice cost',
  4: 'Mail cost',
  5: 'Initial and mail cost',
  6: 'Voice and mail cost',
  7: 'Initial and voice and mail cost'
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select, .voice, .mail").change(function(event) { 
    var sum = 0;
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(row.find('td input.select').is(':checked')) {sum += 1}
    if(row.find('td input.voice').is(':checked')) {sum += 2}
    if(row.find('td input.mail').is(':checked')) {sum += 4}
    row.find('td.out').html(userOptionState[sum]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td>
        <input class="select" type="checkbox" value="select" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="voice" type="checkbox" value="voice">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="mail" type="checkbox" value="mail" />
      </td>
      <!--output td -->
      <td class="out">No cost</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tableRow">
      <td>
        <input class="select" type="checkbox" value="select" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="voice" type="checkbox" value="voice">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="mail" type="checkbox" value="mail" />
      </td>
      <!--output td -->
      <td class="out">No cost</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is undeniably the right way to achieve this - I was lazy in only provided the scoping part. This is a great answer.

Comment: This is really cool but I am looking to put the result of a PHP query later inside that output <td>. i tried your way and the PHP query would not work as expected where as with @Jamiec's response it did. I am not sure why this is so. I think its because the PHP is preloaded the old way where with your way I'd have to put the php in the 'userOptionState' variable. However I did learn something from your answer, I'd imagine if in future I do a similar task, i will try to do it this way since its clearly more streamlined and simpler, so thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.  I only post the essential.

Use the data- attribute to read data; there are many other tricks, but I like this one.

(notice, Jamiec uses the same principle: look for parent, ...)

```
<style>
  td.apples, td.pears, td.lemons {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="apples"  type="checkbox"> apples
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="pears" type="checkbox"> pears
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="lemons" type="checkbox"> lemons
    </td>
    <td class="apples">
      I like apples
    </td>
    <td class="pears">
      I like pears
    </td>
    <td class="lemons">
      I like lemons
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="apples"  type="checkbox"> apples
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="pears" type="checkbox"> pears
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="check" data-fruit="lemons" type="checkbox"> lemons
    </td>
    <td class="apples">
      I like apples (2)
    </td>
    <td class="pears">
      I like pears (2)
    </td>
    <td class="lemons">
      I like lemons (2)
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // event.  click on one of the checkboxes
    $('.check').change(function(e) {
      // on or off?
      var on_off = $(this).is(":checked") ? true : false;   // heredoc notation
      // we read the data-fruit attribute
      var fruit = $(this).data('fruit');
      // now we want to know which row this is, so we find the parent
      var parent_row = $(this).parents('tr');
      // we have the parent, so we can look for children that have the same class as the data-fruit
      var cel = parent_row.find('.' + fruit).css('visibility', on_off ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    })
  })
</script>
```